# List mutability with append in for loop in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, mutability

I'm new to the concept of mutability of lists in the context of for loops.

Can someone explain why the output for the below code is an empty list?

I would expect `L3 = [3,4]`.

Thanks!

```
L1 = [1,2,3,4]
L2 = [1,2,5,6]

def no_dups(L1, L2):
    L3 = []
    for e in L1:
        if e not in L2:
            L3.append(e)
    return(L3)

print(L3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> L1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> L2 = [1,2,5,6]
>>> 
>>> def no_dups(L1, L2):
...     L3 = []
...     for e in L1:
...         if e not in L2:
...             L3.append(e)
...     return(L3)
... 
>>> print(no_dups(L1,L2))
[3, 4]
>>>
```

`L3` does not actually exists outside of `no_dups()`, so you cannot print it or whatever

Answer (score 0):

The last line `print(L3)` does not even call `no_dups` function. It throws an expection because L3 is not defined outside of function.

Probably you meant this:

```
L3 = no_dups(L1, L2)
print(L3)
```

In which case you do inded get the expected result.

Comment: You're not calling `no_dups` either :)